# ContactId field on Case is getting updated automatically

Tags: apex, community, case

I am trying to create a case through Apex from the Custom community portal. I am explicitly setting the value of ContactId field on case while performing the DML. However evrytime contactId field is getting updated with the logged in community user's related contact Id. I have deactivated all the triggers, workflow and process builders but still contactId field is getting updated.

This field update is even showing in the case history section. However I am unable to find the source from where this field is getting updated automatically.

e.g I am creating a case and setting Id of **ContactA** in the ContactId field of Case, however after creation it is automatically getting updated with contact Id of **ContactB**. And **ContactB** is the currently logged in user's related Contact.

Comment: I would first see any Assignment rule or trigger on Case

Comment: I have the same when I try to log a Case with empty ContactId. It is filled with the ContactId of logged community user. I checked that it is empty on Before Trigger and filled on After trigger. I am wondering if it is OOB feature but so far didn't find anything in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it is standard Salesforce behavior. When creating a case from Community ContactId field is automatically set to logged in user's related contact Id.

**Solution**: I created a field on Case named "Contact_Id__c" and stored the Id of Contact which I want to populate on ContactId field on Case.
After Case record is created I called a Queueable class. In the Queueable class I populated ContactId field with value on Contact_Id__c field. It worked perfectly.

**Conclusion**: This scenario can be handled through asynchronous apex.